# Schema Registry + SSL

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

This is the error that I get when I run the command:
bin/schema-registry-start etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties

```
[2019-08-14 18:44:30,596] INFO Logging initialized @2427ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log:193)
[2019-08-14 18:44:32,759] INFO Initializing KafkaStore with broker endpoints: SSL://localhost:9093 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore:105)
[2019-08-14 18:44:33,642] ERROR [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:737)
[2019-08-14 18:44:33,642] ERROR [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:737)
[2019-08-14 18:44:33,650] ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication:68)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryInitializationException: Error initializing kafka store while initializing schema registry
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:224)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.initSchemaRegistry(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:66)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.configureBaseApplication(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:81)
    at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:205)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:42)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.exceptions.StoreInitializationException: Failed trying to create or validate schema topic configuration
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.createOrVerifySchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:179)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.init(KafkaStore.java:116)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:222)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.createOrVerifySchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1521)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:528)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1197)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1165)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeWrap(SslTransportLayer.java:448)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:313)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:547)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1152)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1709)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:318)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:970)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:967)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1459)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:402)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:340)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:231)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:459)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:440)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:261)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1626)
    ... 16 more
```

I am following this tutorial to enable SSL with the Schema Registry:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/security/index.html

This is my schema-registry.properties:
https://pastebin.com/if4P5jiD

Comment: Hi, I am having similar issue as yours, did you solve this problem? Can you suggest the solution if so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding the below listed kafkastore properties in addition to those mentioned in https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/encryption.html#sr in the **schema-registry.properties**

```
kafkastore.ssl.keystore.location=path/to/kafka.server.keystore.jks
kafkastore.ssl.keystore.password=xxxxxx
kafkastore.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm =
```

Please note that I had followed the steps mentioned in the above link to set up SSL encryption and authentication for Kafka and Schema registry.

Hope this helps!